# Как зафиксировать Actor?

Tags: android, libgdx

как можно в одной сцене реализовать перемещение сцены и вызов "модального" (зафиксированного) диалога?

- перемещение реализовано через изменение Stage.camera.position.*
- диалоги реализованы через scene2d.ui

проблема в том, что Dialog из scene2d.ui, для кликабельности, добавляется в Stage как Actor и следовательно перемещается вслед за сценой при перемещении камеры

как можно зафиксировать Dialog ?

**добавил**

```
stage = new Stage() {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
            isDown = true;
            xDown = stage.getCamera().position.x;
            yDown = stage.getCamera().position.y;
            screenX0 = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - screenX;
            screenY0 = screenY;
            return false;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        super.touchUp(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);

        isDown = false;
        screenX0 = 0;
        screenY0 = 0;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        super.touchDragged(screenX, screenY, pointer);
        if(isDown) {
            stage.getCamera().position.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() + xDown - screenX - screenX0;
            stage.getCamera().position.y = yDown + screenY - screenY0;

        }
        return false;
    }
}

table = new Table();
table.setFillParent(true);
stage.addActor(table);
```

...

```
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*5);
    stage.draw();

    table.setPosition(stage.getCamera().position.x, stage.getCamera().position.y);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта:
1) Создать 2 stage с разными камерами - один для актеров, второй для UI;
2) Привязать UI к камере:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    ui.setPosition(camera.position.x, camera.position.y);
}
```

Comment: 1. для кликабельности у меня стоит `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage)` , если добавить `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage2)` то форма не реагирует на клики. 2. какую камеру Вы предлагаете привязать к ui? Если Stage.camera, то я ее изменяю, для перемещения самой сцены

Comment: попробовал 2-й вариант, с камерой (код показал в вопросе). диалог фиксируется, но при перемещении сцены он подергивается, как можно этого избежать?

Comment: 1) Если нужно обрабатывать ввод от нескольких источников, то для этого есть InputMultiplexer; 2) Судя по коду при создании stage используется конструктор без параметров, а значит создавая два stage будут 2 камеры - одну перемещаем, в вторую не трогаем; 3) Чтобы исправить подергивание нужно table.setPosition поместить между stage.act и stage.draw.